# How to increase and fit ImageView in CardView

Tags: android, cardview

I'm using some TextView and CardView in Recycle with android property: `android:orientation="vertical"`, when I change `layout_width` and `layout_height` of ImageView, it doesn't change size of ImageView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cardview1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardElevation="3dp"
    card_view:contentPadding="3dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    card_view:cardMaxElevation="3dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
            android:id="@+id/VollyNetworkImageView1"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:gravity="top" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:id="@+id/textView_item"
            android:text="Image View"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>

      </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I have tried a lot of ways but I have not got it yet, I wish it same with file photo attachment
[image]

How to fix the problem ? Thank so much !

Comment: Kindly provide more detail. Are you changing the width and height programatically or in the xml. Have you tried using scaletype and adjustViewBounds in the xml?

Comment: Im not try, maybe I should be try now..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just need to add the `android:scaleType` attribute to your ImageView.

Comment: Could you tell me value of android:scaleType ?

Comment: Base on the screenshot of how you would like it to look like, I know that kind of view normally use: `centerCrop`

Comment: it seem better for me, I will back... :)

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

This will scale your image to fit the size of your ImageView